# Filter PostgreSQL traffic by table in Wireshark

Tags: postgresql, wireshark

I've been able to properly capture PGSQL traffic regarding queries using [`pgsql.query`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/p/pgsql.html) in Wireshark v2.6.2-0-g1b3cedbc (MacOS) and, although there is a filter called `table_name` , I don't see a way of filtering the traffic by table name.

The following filter returns an empty set although there have been queries against a particular table:

```
pgsql.query && pgsql.table_name eq "workers"
```

Do you have any idea of what I could do to make this work?

**The whole goal is to be able to set a filter like `pgsql.table_name eq "mytable"` and see all the queries that are made against such table.**

Thanks!

Comment: According to the documentation, this should work. Maybe try to replace `eq` with  `contains`.